# How to find the length of an integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, int

I want to be able to find the length of a certain value within an array. I have tried:

```
String.valueOf(array[arrayValue])
```

but I am unable to see if it is < a certain number within an if statement. For example I want to see if the length of the certain value at hand is less than four. I have something like this right now:

```
if(String.valueOf(array[arrayValue] < 4)){
    //does something
}
```

However it says that I cannot use the "<" sign for some reason. Does anyone know how I would successfully be able to do this?

Comment: How do you define the *length of integer*?

Comment: What is the type of `array`?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `array[arrayValue].length`

Comment: It is an int array, just as the title says. Also what I mean by the length of an integer is say for example the integer: 123 has a value of 123, but has a length of three digits. I want to use that in an if statement.

Comment: @Kousha are you sure that would work?

Comment: @person3124 `array[arrayValue].toString().length` This one will work!

Comment: What is the exact error? If it is true that `array` is an `int[]`, then the statement `String.valueOf(array[arrayValue] < 4)` shouldn't emit any exception.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes it would. the OP is trying to pass a String to an if clause

Comment: @k_g The compiler would not complain about the `<` sign; it will only complain about the unability to convert a String to a boolean.

Comment: @MCEmperor I'm guessing that the OP misunderstood what the compiler was telling him/her

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
if(Integer.toString(array[arrayValue]).length()>4)
```

This takes the `arrayValue`th element from your array, converts it to a `String`, finds the length, then compares that to `4`.

Your current code is taking the `arrayValue`th element from your array, comparing it to `4`, and then converting the result of the comparison `true` or `false` to a String: `"true"` or `"false"`. It is then trying to pass the `String` to the `if` clause, which only takes boolean, so its throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the code not being compiled is already pointed out by [k_g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549476/k-g).
However, your statement

> it says that I cannot use the "<" sign for some reason

is not entirely true: `String.valueOf(array[arrayValue] < 4)` is perfectly valid, but it returns a String, and that's not possible as condition in an if-statement.

#### Getting the 'length' of an integer

To calculate the length – I prefer to say 'width' – of an integer, there are two approaches:

- One might want to convert the integer to a string and getting the length of the string, see [k_g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549476/k-g)'s answer, but **conversion to string is expensive**.
- A better approach might be this:
  Repeatedly divide the given value by 10 until it drops below 1:

  ```
  public static int getWidth(int value) {
      int i = 0;
      while (value > 0) {
          value /= 10;
          i++;
      }
      return i;
  }
  ```

  It avoids int-to-string conversion, making it **approximately 5.6 times faster**.